# Is it possible to change output of Class.getName()?

Tags: java, class

Is it possible to change the output of `MyClass.class.getName()`? Example:

```
public class MyClass {
}

public static main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println(MyClass.class.getName());
}
```

1. The output should not be 'MyClass' but rather 'whatever'. Is this
   possible?
2. Furthermore: If we can change the output to 'whatever',
   can we completely control the call to Myclass.class.getName(),
   similar to overwriting the method?

Why I am asking: I have a program (which I do not control) that dynamically loads MyClass (`MyClassLoader.loadClass('MyClass')`) and calls `MyClass.class.getName()`.

edit:
I better restate some facts for clearness:

-MyClass is loaded dynamically by a class loader with `Class new_class = loadClass('MyClass')`. I cannot change this code, it is not part of the question.

-Next thing that happens: `System.out.println(new_class.class.getName())`
---> The problem: This call goes to `java.lang.Class<T>.getName()` and will of course return 'MyClass'. Is there a way of changing that output?

Comment: Change class name from `MyClass` to `whatever`.

Comment: Try MyClass.getClass().getSimpleName(). You'll get String, Integer, or whatever back.

Comment: To easy, the name of the class is hardcoded into the other program. The program loads 'MyClass'. See my edit "(which I do not control)"

Comment: Thanks for the link, I saw that one - however I could not reproduce the result without annotation, just using one class.

Comment: Can you change the system design? Your requirements are really weird.

Comment: I can see that this is weird. Since I only control 'MyClass' I cannot change the prerequisites and a hacky solution is needed.
However, the link above seems to provide a solution using aspectj - I would need one without aspectj, just using the class 'MyClass'. If it is possible at all.

Comment: **Why?** Of course you can't do it. Your requirement doesn't begin to make sense. And you haven't actually stated why, you've just restated the requirement. It is unimplementable.

Comment: Sometimes things that look impossible are possible after all, see http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/28786/write-a-program-that-makes-2-2-5 Should you (try to) do it? No! (except for fun of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The output should not be 'MyClass' but rather 'whatever'. Is this possible?

Nope.

Certainly not in pure Java.

And I'm struggling to think of a way that would be *theoretically* possible using bytecode engineering or classloader hackery.  (You could potentially use bytecode engineering to change the classes name to `something` before loading, but then it wouldn't load with its old name `MyClass`.)

One reason that this door is "nailed shut" is that class names are intimately associated with their identity ... which is intimately associated with Java runtime type safety and security.  If you could "hack" this, there would be a risk that it could lead to security holes.

---

Advice: think of another approach so that you don't have this requirement.

Comment: The link I got earlier in the comments gave me some hope, even though I already had the feeling it was impossible. Thanks for the answer.